# Cassandra Query doesn't return any data

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-enterprise

I am using a Cassandra Repository to fetch data from the database.
I use the following query (to be as simple as possible):

```
public interface PersonReposiroty extends CassandraRepository<Person>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM KeySp.person WHERE joinTime >= 21 ALLOW FILTERING")
    public List<Person> findByTime();
}
```

When this is called by the Java statement :

```
List<Person> persons = repository.findByTime();
```

It produces a `NullPointerException`.

In fact, any query that should return any data from the DB shows the Exception.

At the same time `Update`, `Delete`, `Save` functions work perfectly when implemented using the above repository.

Please tell me where am I going wrong and how to get it done.  (I use `Spring Boot`)

THANKS in Advance.

My Person Entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person", indexes = { @Index(name="peson_index", columnList = "joinTime, category, personId") })
public class Person {

    @Id
    @PrimaryKeyColumn
    private PersonContext context;

    @Column(name = "address", columnDefinition = "LONGTEXT")
    private String address;

    public PersonContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(PersonContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

And PersonContext.java is

```
@Embeddable
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class PersonContext implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;

    @NotNull
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "joinTime", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private long joinTime;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "person_id", length = 50)
    private String personId = StringUtils.EMPTY;

    public long getjoinTime() {
        return joinTime;
    }

    public void setjoinTime(long joinTime) {
        this.joinTime = joinTime;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(String personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }
```

}

Stack Trace:

```
    ForgivingExceptionHandler: Consumer com.User.service.CacheService$1@6e6c7b7a (amq.ctag-6VuMjQcL3vjdfed2yC78zA) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://user@155.83.167.923:5672/,1) threw an exception for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@159.89.169.123:5672/,1)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:259)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:233)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readProperties(MappingCassandraConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readPropertiesFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readEntityFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.read(MappingCassandraConverter.java:298)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraConverterRowCallback.doWith(CassandraConverterRowCallback.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.processResultSet(CassandraTemplate.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:594)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:376)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:113)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.findByResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy142.findByTime()
    at User.StatisticsCacheService.storeDataInternal(StatisticsCacheService.java:46)
    at User.CacheService$1.handleDelivery(CacheService.java:54)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-31 13:02:48,193 ERROR [User-scheduler-2] TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler: Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed due to clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=Closed due to exception from Consumer (amq.ctag-6VuMjQcL3vjdfed2yC78zA) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@159.89.169.123:5672/,1), class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:253)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:336)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.basicConsume(ChannelN.java:1365)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicConsume(AutorecoveringChannel.java:540)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicConsume(AutorecoveringChannel.java:494)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.basicConsume(AutorecoveringChannel.java:472)
    at User.service.CacheService.cacheDataInternal(CacheService.java:59)
    at User.service.periodic.StatisticsCacheService.cacheData(StatisticsCacheService.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please add a stacktrace (Error that you got in logs ).. to figure out why is this happening ??

also add your Entity Class `Person` too

Comment: Now, It can only identify by error stacktrace... but still unable to trace but I think problem with your query that you have written in `@Query` Annotation (for sure).

Comment: Any Query with `@Query` annotation that does not return any value such as delete, save or update works fine when I use the same technique. Moreover, if I use the same query `SELECT * FROM person.details WHERE joinTime >= 21 ALLOW FILTERING;` in the Cassandra server I get the resultSet. The problem happens when I try to fetch from Java.

Comment: I have added the stack Trace too to the Query above.  But i believe that it says **the Connection is closed** This probably is because the NPE caused the connection close and can't connect to the server anymore.

Comment: if you closely look into your exception stacktrace it show `com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException:` which is totally unrelated with cassandra.. Please add complete stacktrace not a part of.. above exception raised from rabbitmq messaging api not by cassandra.. so please add complete stacktrace.

Thank You :)

Comment: I haven't used Cassandra before, but I have used spring data jpa and elasticsearch. What I see is a few typo's: `@Index(name="peson_index"`, `public interface PersonReposiroty`.
Then, in your @Query, you query `person.details`, but I can't find any 'details' in your provided code. Perhaps that's the NPE?

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I have added the complete stackTrace. and I believe `AlreadyClosedException` is caused because the NPE caused all the connections that I had created to close. Basically, I'm tracking the data from RabbitMQ server and saving it in the DB and then retrieving that data from the DB and showing it to the client. This might seem complicated but this is how I want the program to work. The NPE causes the connection between the RabbitMQ server and java to close hence that Exception.

Comment: @evandongen In cassandra we have to specify the keyspace and the table name to do operations on a table.. 

 In my query Keysp is the keyspace and person is the table name hence
Keysp.person.

Comment: @user8622966 I see you changed the query. This seems logical ;)